A movie about teenagers escaping death by car accident
I remember watching this movie on TV when I was a little.
Probably about 10 years ago or more.
I don't remember the title nor the story, but I remember this scene. There are three teenagers in a car. An accident happens and the car falls to the water and drowns. Three of them cannot survive, but magically the spirits of them are outside the lake (in my memory it's a lake, could be sea as well). They realise they are dead, but since they're still "alive", they live their lives as usual even go to school. People can still see and interact with them like when they're still alive.
That's all I can remember.
Does anybody know what movie is that?

Please see Identify-This-X Questions guide on how to write good identify this movie question. For example add better descriptive title, origin-country, colour, decade, language, plot details, actors etc. of the movie.

Might it be Carnival of Souls from 1962? 
Car accident (the car falls off a bridge and sinks in the river below), three teenagers, weird death, but no school stuff. 

One was a survivor. She got a job as an organ player and moved to Salt Lake City where there was an (haunted) amusement park with ghouls.

Sometimes she could not interact with her surroundings. Nobody could see or hear her. It was just for a moment here and there.
Spoiler alert! 

 She died in the car accident at the beginning of the movie.

